# Tomcat SSL Certificate Intermediate

Tags: tomcat, ssl, ssl-certificate

i started with an keystore with `keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -keystore eakte.keystore`

Then i generated the CSR `keytool -certreq -keyalg RSA -file eakte.csr -keystore eakte.keystore` and submitted to comodo. I got four files:

- AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt
- COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt
- COMODORSAOrganizationValidationSecureServerCA.crt
- eakte_example_com.crt

I added from top to bottom (Key Chain) to the Keystore. Example `keytool.exe -import -trustcacerts -alias intermediate_COMODORSAAddTrustCA -file COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt -keystore eakte.keystore`

With keystore -list i see all certificates.

If I add this file as key file at the Tomcat Server.xml, i get at the start of the Service, the message error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line)

Ok i converted the file to PKCS#12 with `keytool.exe -importkeystore -srckeystore eakte.keystore -destkeystore eakte.p12 -srcstoretype jks -deststoretype pkcs12` and the with open_ssl to pem `openssl pkcs12 -in eakte.p12 -out eakte.pem`

No error in log files....

But a quick check with open_ssl i see the error Verify
return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate) and ssllabs say the same.

What is my mistake? Do i think wrong? I want to understand the issue.

Best regards,

Stefan

Comment: How did you test it on ssllabs?
Do you have a public domain? If yes then share the domain name to identify the issue correctly.